# android emulator launch of worklight app fails with message "can't load wlclient.properties file"

Tags: android, android-emulator, ibm-mobilefirst, ddms

Since i first encountered this failure to start a worklight application in the android emulator, i have re-installed the ADT package, upgraded to Luna with reinstallation of the ecplipse plug-ins for ADT and worklight.  i import the project from the kepler instance and run the common app successfully.  The error message is pretty clear that it can't load the wlclient.properties file, but i can't figure out why.  i have changed the read-only attribute and granted everyone full control.  the wlclient.properties file does exist in the native assets folder and when i open it, there are no problems and the information seems right.  i am using a standard device definition and i have tried a new device as well.  Here is the stack dump from DDMS:

```
10-23 11:34:55.770: D/dalvikvm(1749): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
10-23 11:34:55.850: W/ResourceType(1749): No known package when getting value for resource number 0x7f040000
10-23 11:34:55.850: W/PackageManager(1749): Failure retrieving text 0x7f040000 in package com.JSONstore
10-23 11:34:55.850: W/PackageManager(1749): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f040000
10-23 11:34:55.850: W/PackageManager(1749):     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:244)
10-23 11:34:55.850: W/PackageManager(1749):     at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getText(ApplicationPackageManager.java:994)
10-23 11:34:55.850: W/PackageManager(1749):     at android.content.pm.ComponentInfo.loadLabel(ComponentInfo.java:85)
10-23 11:34:55.850: W/PackageManager(1749):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
10-23 11:34:55.850: W/PackageManager(1749):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
10-23 11:34:55.850: W/PackageManager(1749):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
10-23 11:34:55.850: W/PackageManager(1749):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
10-23 11:34:55.850: W/PackageManager(1749):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-23 11:34:55.850: W/PackageManager(1749):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-23 11:34:55.850: W/PackageManager(1749):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
10-23 11:34:55.850: W/PackageManager(1749):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-23 11:34:55.850: W/PackageManager(1749):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-23 11:34:55.850: W/PackageManager(1749):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
10-23 11:34:55.850: W/PackageManager(1749):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
10-23 11:34:55.850: W/PackageManager(1749):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-23 11:34:55.850: W/ResourceType(1749): No known package when getting value for resource number 0x7f040000
10-23 11:34:55.850: W/PackageManager(1749): Failure retrieving text 0x7f040000 in package com.JSONstore
10-23 11:34:55.850: W/PackageManager(1749): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f040000
10-23 11:34:55.850: W/PackageManager(1749):     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:244)
10-23 11:34:55.850: W/PackageManager(1749):     at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getText(ApplicationPackageManager.java:994)
10-23 11:34:55.850: W/PackageManager(1749):     at android.content.pm.ComponentInfo.loadLabel(ComponentInfo.java:94)
10-23 11:34:55.850: W/PackageManager(1749):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
10-23 11:34:55.850: W/PackageManager(1749):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
10-23 11:34:55.850: W/PackageManager(1749):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
10-23 11:34:55.850: W/PackageManager(1749):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
10-23 11:34:55.850: W/PackageManager(1749):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-23 11:34:55.850: W/PackageManager(1749):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-23 11:34:55.850: W/PackageManager(1749):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
10-23 11:34:55.850: W/PackageManager(1749):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-23 11:34:55.850: W/PackageManager(1749):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-23 11:34:55.850: W/PackageManager(1749):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
10-23 11:34:55.850: W/PackageManager(1749):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
10-23 11:34:55.850: W/PackageManager(1749):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-23 11:34:55.900: D/AndroidRuntime(1749): Shutting down VM
10-23 11:34:55.900: W/dalvikvm(1749): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb0d8fb20)
10-23 11:34:55.950: E/AndroidRuntime(1749): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-23 11:34:55.950: E/AndroidRuntime(1749): Process: com.JSONstore, PID: 1749
10-23 11:34:55.950: E/AndroidRuntime(1749): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.JSONstore/com.JSONstore.JSONstore}: java.lang.RuntimeException: WLConfig(): Can't load wlclient.properties file
10-23 11:34:55.950: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
10-23 11:34:55.950: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
10-23 11:34:55.950: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
10-23 11:34:55.950: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
10-23 11:34:55.950: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-23 11:34:55.950: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-23 11:34:55.950: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
10-23 11:34:55.950: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-23 11:34:55.950: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-23 11:34:55.950: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
10-23 11:34:55.950: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
10-23 11:34:55.950: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-23 11:34:55.950: E/AndroidRuntime(1749): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: WLConfig(): Can't load wlclient.properties file
10-23 11:34:55.950: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     at com.worklight.common.WLConfig.<init>(WLConfig.java:90)
10-23 11:34:55.950: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     at com.worklight.common.WLConfig.createInstance(WLConfig.java:96)
10-23 11:34:55.950: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     at com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLClient.createInstance(WLClient.java:190)
10-23 11:34:55.950: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     at com.worklight.common.Logger.setContext(Logger.java:478)
10-23 11:34:55.950: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     at com.worklight.androidgap.api.WL.<init>(WL.java:54)
10-23 11:34:55.950: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     at com.worklight.androidgap.api.WL.createInstance(WL.java:84)
10-23 11:34:55.950: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     at com.JSONstore.JSONstore.onCreate(JSONstore.java:20)
10-23 11:34:55.950: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
10-23 11:34:55.950: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
10-23 11:34:55.950: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
10-23 11:34:55.950: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     ... 11 more
10-23 11:34:55.990: D/dalvikvm(1749): GC_CONCURRENT freed 267K, 10% free 2972K/3296K, paused 19ms+0ms, total 70ms
```

and here is the content of the wlclient.properties file.

```
wlServerProtocol = http
wlServerHost = 10.99.12.160
wlServerPort = 10080
wlServerContext = /FunWith/
wlAppId = JSONstore
wlAppVersion = 1.0
GcmSenderId = 
enableSettings = false
testWebResourcesChecksum = false
ignoredFileExtensions =  
webResourcesSize = 3462895
wlUid = kiWaVxEDXAUfwn/fyz3V8w==
wlPlatformVersion = 6.2.0.00.20140613-0730
wlMainFilePath = index.html
wlShareCookies = 
wlShareUserCert = false
```

(i changed the host name to an ip address as a test.)

Any ideas out there?

Thanks,
Parke

Comment: 1) Is this a Worklight sample application or your own application? 2) Does it work in a physical device or does it fail just like in the emulator? 3) You are using a very old version of Worklight; download the latest version from the Eclipse Marketplace (Help > marketplace).

Comment: 4) if you create a new application > add android environment > run as - run on worklight development server > run as - android application; does it work?

Comment: did you try the above?

Comment: This has taken a while, because i was trying to isolate the problem: "application error" 
net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND (file:///android_asset/www/skinLoader.html.    Again, the file does in fact exist in the location specified.  i suspect that some configured path or context root is not set up correctly but i can't see that.  This is a custom app, using dojo, an sql adapter, and jsonstore. The app fails with the identical message when deployed to a physical device.  i am on the latest version of worklight, however:  v6.2.  - parke

Comment: Make sure you're loading all require dojo components in the application; I would also advice to start fresh and then add pieces to see when it fails. Also make sure that if you are not adding all dojo components, then to enable the dojo console which will supply the missing components during testing; read the dojo user documentation in the IBM Worklight Knowledge Center for more information; I suspect that is what causing the timeout and the app can't work.

Comment: Idan, you were correct that i am using an old version of worklight.  is just updated it to fixpack 1 (6.4.0.1) dated 10/13, but i get the same behavior.  i assumed if i installed a new eclipse, used a different workspace, then i would get a separate/new server config.    i did ensure that i am loading the dojo apps, but i do see some weird behavior in that one of the custom classes is constantly identified as needing a refresh, and i see 2 sources in chrome debug.  i am going to tear down and rebuild next.

Comment: I built another environment on a VM:  windows 8.1, worklight 6.2.0.1, latest android plugin/sdk, and configured an AVD with atom/hax to run API level 19.  That worked.  i did not get the failure to find wlclient.properties.  So will go back to my windows 7 workstation, tear it all down and rebuild since my original attempt was to simply create a separate development/test environment failed.  wish i could isolate why my android emulator can't find relative locations...

Comment: Is your application pure web resources or did you write any native code? If it's pure web, I would maybe delete the native folder and let worklight rebuild it from scratch...

Comment: @user3208130, have you reached any conclusions?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the discussion in the comments, this appears to have been a local configuration issue.

> I built another environment on a VM: windows 8.1, worklight 6.2.0.1,
>   latest android plugin/sdk, and configured an AVD with atom/hax to run
>   API level 19. That worked. i did not get the failure to find
>   wlclient.properties.